# Would choose vs. Chose

Tags: grammar

A recent study of children aged between four and eleven years old has revealed that their notion of the ideal home presents major challenges to conventional wisdom. More than a quarter of the youngest group expressed a desire to live in a house made either entirely of sweets or of toys rather than more traditional materials. One in four boys and nearly half the girls ***would choose*** to live in a fairytale castle.

I wonder if it will be acceptable to replace "would choose" with "chose";and if the answer is positive, will there be any difference in meaning?

Comment: Why would you want to? What do you think you would be changing about that sentence?

Comment: @JMB: As a non-native speaker, I would go for "chose" but I'm not sure whether it is proper English or not. On the other had, I'd like to know why a native speaker has chosen this structure and what has he/she tried to express through this choice?

Comment: Would choose, definitely!

Comment: I would choose would choose … I'd also like to live in a fairytale castle ;)

Answer (score 2):

They cannot choose to live in a fairy-tale castle because no such castles exist. So we cannot say 'they chose'. But *if* such castles existed, they *would choose* to live in one.

Answer (score 1):

"Chose" concretely talks about the children who took part in the study. "Would choose" refers to children in general. The conditional (would) is used to express something similar to the following:

> If children could choose their ideal home, one in four boys and nearly half of girls **would choose** to live in a fairytale castle.

Answer (score 0):

The construction is `would+normal verb` to show the future possibility. If you want 'chosen' i.e. participle, the format is `would+have+chosen`. If you want 'would chose', I'm afraid, it's **incorrect.**

Now, why did the author *would choose* to write that way? :)

Well, when you talk about general things, future things **or** someone's wish *as you predict*, you use such construction.

In present context, you are predicting their *(obvious)* choice.

> One in four boys and nearly half the girls would choose to live in a fairytale castle.

You may also come up with other examples:

> I *would buy* Bentley over Audi 
>  She *would prefer* a French movie during weekends 
>  He *would play* baseball, and not cricket

In all these sentences, you are *predicting* the actions. **One of the uses** of the format *'would+normal verb'* is that.

Again, be careful, *would chose* is incorrect; don't use it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but could we say "would has chosen"?!As far as I know only "would have chosen", in your example, is correct.

Comment: Oh yes...I just missed it. Corrected. :)